# SQL: Using 6 clauses in different ways to get the same query

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Question:

> For each department that has more than five employees , retrieve the
>   department number and the number  of its employees  who are making
>   more than $40,000.

Answer1:

```
select dnumber,count(*)
from   department,employee
where  dnumber=dno and salary>40000 and 
  dno in (select dno from employee group by dno having count(*)>5)
group by dnumber;
```

Answer2:

```
SELECT  Dnumber , COUNT(*)
  FROM     DEPARTMENT, EMPLOYEE
  WHERE    Dnumber= Dno AND Salary > 40,000
  GROUP BY Dnumber
  HAVING  COUNT(*)>5;
```

Link to course: https://www.mscs.mu.edu/~praveen/Teaching/Fa06/Db/Lectures/ch8-queries.sql

Answer2 is my try. I am not sure if it's correct. It is more intuitive to me than the first answer. Are they the same? if not, what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Your query requires the department to have more than 5 employees making 40k.  Not just more than 5, then counting the employees making the specified salary (which might be less than 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the two queries do not return the same resultset and your query does not comply with the requirements.

Your query list those departments only, which have more than 5 employees earning 40k along with the number of such employees. But the requirements say that first determine the list of departments that have more than 5 employees and then list the number of employees who earn more than 40k.

If a department has 6 employees, but only 1 of them earns more than 40k, then your query will not pick this up, but the first one will.

However, I do not think that the first query is completely correct either because departments with more than 5 employees, but having no one above 40k will not show up on the list. I would have used a left join:

```
select dnumber,count(employee.dno)
from   department
left join employee on department.dnumber=employee.dno and employee.salary>40000 
where dno in (select dno from employee group by dno having count(*)>5)
group by dnumber;
```